# "Streng gegen jmdn" or "Streng mit jmdm"?

Tags: grammar, difference, preposition

What is the difference between *streng mit jmdm* and *streng gegen jmdn*:

> Ich bin streng damit, dass ich mein Haus sauber halte.
>
> Er ist streng dagegen, dass seine Freundin mit ihren Freunden ausgeht.

Comment: Your examples do not fit the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example *Ich bin streng damit, dass ich mein Haus sauber halte.* would be more common as

> Ich achte streng darauf, dass ich mein Haus sauber halte.

Another sentence with *streng mit*:

> Er ist streng mit sich selbst.

He adheres strictly to his principles.

So *streng mit jemandem/etwas sein* means to be hard on someone or e.g. the results of his work.

> Ich bin *streng dagegen*, dass …

I am *strictly opposed to* …

Same for *streng gegen*.

Comment: A more litteral but still common translation of the first sentence would be `Ich bin streng darin, mein Haus sauber zu halten.`.

Answer (score 2):

A short explanation in addition to very good examples in the other answers:

`streng mit jemandem sein/umgehen` and `streng in etwas sein` are fixed phrases meaning `to be hard on someone` resp. `to adhere to principles`.

In contrast, `streng gegen etwas sein` is a combination of the fixed phrase `gegen etwas sein` meaning `to be opposed to` and the adverbial `streng` meaning `strictly`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use different examples:

> Ich bin streng mit meinen Schülern

vs.

> Ich bin streng gegen die Todesstrafe

The latter would usually be put as

> Ich bin strikt gegen Todesstrafe (I'm strictly opposed to...)